# Untestable part of Code

Tags: java, junit

I have a class which is not instantiated and is composed of static methods only. I managed to cover all the parts of the getProperty() except the catch(IOException e) part, however the code seems to be unreachable.

```
public class ResourceUtils
{

    private static final String IOEXCEPTION_ERROR_MESSAGE = "ERROR: Problem reading StringBundles.properties";

    private static final String PATH_STRING_BUNDLE = "com/qn/config/StringBundles.properties";

    public static String getProperty( String key )
    {
        Properties property = new Properties();
        try
        {
            property.load( ResourceUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( PATH_STRING_BUNDLE ) );
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            System.err.println( IOEXCEPTION_ERROR_MESSAGE );
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return property.getProperty( key );
    }
```

I wanted to test the scenario where in the PATH_STRING_BUNDLE would be invalid and it wall pass through the catch(IOException e). However the PATH_STRING_BUNDLE has a final modifier. Can you suggest a way to test this or is testing this part pretty useless or maybe the design of the class have problems.

Comment: If it's really unreachable, then I would put something like `throw new AssertionError(e);` in there, so that later if it does become reachable it's really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In your Unit test, temporarily rename the file `com/qn/config/StringBundles.properties`, and then run the code. When the test is complete, rename it back.

Answer (score 0):

In this situations I usually introduce use this immediate solution (there's also a cleaner solution but it requires wider refactoring): I create a new overload of the method, which takes one extra parameter, and uses this parameter in place of the `PATH_STRING_BUNDLE` constant. Then I change the original method such that it simply passes `PATH_STRING_BUNDLE` to the new overload. Here's how the code looks like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ResourceUtils
{
    private static final String IOEXCEPTION_ERROR_MESSAGE = "ERROR: Problem reading StringBundles.properties";

    private static final String PATH_STRING_BUNDLE = "com/qn/config/StringBundles.properties";

    public static String getProperty(String key) {
      return getProperty(key, PATH_STRING_BUNDLE);
    }

    static String getProperty(String key, String bundlePath)
    {
        Properties property = new Properties();
        try
        {
            property.load(ResourceUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(bundlePath));
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            System.err.println( IOEXCEPTION_ERROR_MESSAGE );
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return property.getProperty( key );
    }
}
```

Now you can test the scenario where the bundle path is broken simply by calling the new overload passing in whatever value you want for the second parameter.